# Cant change niceness even after editing limits.conf

Tags: 12.04, system-monitor, process-priority, nice

so what i did: 
in the terminal i typed:

```
sudo su
```

(used pass) then typed:

```
nano /etc/security/limits.conf
```

went to bottom and added: 
`USER             -       nice            -20` 
(with my username not user and i spaced it properly) 
then i restarted my comp, but it still didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Reading this link, I think you need not issue the command as su. You can simply run the `ulimit -a` command.

http://lzone.de/apply+limits+immediately

Although reading the man page for `ulimit`, it says that this routine is obsolete and you should use `getrlimit`, `setrlimit` and `sysconf` instead.

Comment: ive followed the link you sent me, but when i go to the system monitor and try to change the niceness of things all i get back is an error:

    Cannot change the priority of process with PID 2190 to -20.
Permission denied

Comment: Did you try the `getrlimit`, `setrlimit` and `sysconf` commands? You'll need to read the man pages first. In a terminal, type `man setrlimit` then press the Enter key, and use the 'q' key to exit the man page.

Answer (score 0):

The `<item>` you're looking for is `priority` which sets the default priority to run a user's processes with, not `nice`.

`nice` is the MAX nice priority allowed, not default.

I recommend using `top` or `renice` to change a process's priority for one time.